# SqlBulkCopy - Importing XML data into SQL table

Tags: .net, xml, dataset, xmldocument, sqlbulkcopy

I'm having proplems with importing an XML file using `SqlBulkCopy`. The XML file looks like this:

```
   <root>
    <Automobiles>
        <Car Id="1" Name="SomeModel1"/>
        <Car Id="2" Name="SomeModel2"/>
        <Car Id="3" Name="SomeModel2"/>
    </Automobiles>
   </root>
```

My table looks like this:

```
Int         Id
varchar    Name
```

Here is my code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("autolist.xml"));

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString());
SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
sbc.DestinationTableName = "Automobiles";

foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(dc.Caption, dc.Caption);
}

connection.Open();

sbc.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);

connection.Close();
```

I could only import the `Id` but not Name because its attribute and the `DataSet` contains only one column. Is there any way to map the attributes to columns?

Maybe its better to use `XmlDocument` instead of `DataSet`?

I think i what is wrong. Dataset is quite different when i have some root element around Automobiles element and columns are missing in Dataset tables. It works well without root element.

Comment: I've tried importing your code and the DateSet has 2 columns (Id and Name) so that can't be the problem. Could something go wrong with your mapping?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will check my mappings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally don't like using a [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) to import XML data into my database; the `DataSet` class has a very specific way of structuring its data as XML and conversely, reading other XML.

That said, I prefer call the [`WriteToServer` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx) that takes an [`IDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) implementation.

You can easily create an extension method that takes an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) implementation and maps it to an `IDataReader`; basically, you map the properties of the class to the fields on the table by name and index where the index is also an index into an array of [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) instances (compiled to lambdas) that you create for `T` which takes the instance of `T` and returns the property value.

You'd generally map the [`IDataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx) implementation to [`IEnumerable<T>.MoveNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) method.

Once you have something like this in place, you can map your XML to a lightwieght data object which mirrors the table and then pass the sequence of them into an extension method which maps the sequence to an `IDataReader` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did some resarch after your answer and found som examples.